# When will FireFox support websockets?

Tags: ajax, firefox, websocket, polling

I know that it's possible to enable websocket support in FireFox, but does anyone know when they will fully support it? Using a websocket is so much nicer than using AJAX polling >.<

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is **Firefox 7**.

Firefox 6 will support WebSockets, but I believe it's an earlier draft of the WebSocket spec, version 7 ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Browser_support))

For the latest draft of the WebSocket spec (version 8) you'll have to wait until Firefox 7 (though you can try it out now in the Aurora build of Firefox which is basically Firefox 7).

I believe the differences between v7 and v8 of the WS spec are breaking ([source](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-websocket/pull/51)). Though there's now good chance that v8 of the WS spec will be the last.

So to sum up:

- Firefox 6 = WebSocket v7
- Firefox 7 = WebSocket v8

I'm currently building a web app that uses WebSockets v8 and I'm testing it using Firefox Aurora (AKA Firefox 7) and Chrome Canary (AKA Chrome 15).

Comment: I voted for your answer because Websocket V8 is technically about as final as it gets. However, they're up to V13 now based on hybi-17; which has been submitted to become the actual standard.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, Firefox 6.

But this doesn't mean that WebSockets can't be used at all. Fallback to Flash using something like [websocket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) means that it's not something you necessarily need to worry too much about.

websocket-js means that WebSockets can be used via the polyfill technique and can therefore be made available in any browser with Flash 10 installed.